# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null at splitDepsDsl

Tags: angular, webpack

There is a problem that I don't know to why

When following code line be commented, problem is not shown.

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
at splitDepsDsl (core.es5.js:8712)
at _def (core.es5.js:10695)
at directiveDef (core.es5.js:10652)
at View_AppComponent_Host_0 (AppComponent_Host.html:1)
at proxyClass (compiler.es5.js:14963)
at resolveDefinition (core.es5.js:8756)
at ComponentFactory_.ac_app../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9859)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.ac_app../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
at ApplicationRef_.ac_app../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4768)
at core.es5.js:4546
```

Comment: Please add the code that causes the issue. It's impossible to make suggestions. (Except that you need to fix your code to make the error go away).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is right, please put more effort into asking a question and you'll dramatically increase your chances of getting an answer!

Comment: When following code be commented, problem is not has.

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));

 "@angular/core": "^4.2.6",